# Validate the image and video file names based on folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I am new to nodejs and i am trying to validate file naming convention like images and video naming based on current folder and sub folder structure.

I have a root folder name Subject(Science) and its sub folder name Physics and this physics folder contains images and videos folder and these folder contains images and videos respectively  like this :-

Science_Physics_002_IMG_002 -> Translates to Science Subject/Physics_ID/Image Number 2.png

Science_Physics_002_VD_002 -> Translates to Science Subject/Physics_ID/Video Number 2.mp4

The subject folder can contain multiple sub folders like physics, math, english
So i need to write a text case in node js to validate image and video file names  based on the current folder structure that the images and video names are following the root and sub folder naming convention .

Example:-

Suppose i have a folder Science(root folder) this folder container multiple subfolders like SC MLO_101 and SC MLO_102
(these both two folders are subfolders within Science folder) .Now SC MLO 101 subfolder contain multiple subfolders within it like SC_MLO_101_DOK1 and SC MLO 101 subfolder also contain multiple subfolders like SC_MLO_101_DOK2 and again these two new folders SC_MLO_101_DOK1 and SC_MLO_102_DOK2 contains img folder. And img folder contain multiple image files but images names will follow the folder structure like SC_MLO_101_IMG_001.png and SC_MLO_102_IMG_001.png. So i need to write a test case in nodejs to validate this folder structure and image file names(folder and subfolder structure will also be validated).

Comment: What did you try and what precise part was a problem here ?

Comment: Hi @DenysSéguret  i am not able to plan that how would i do this. Sorry for bothering you.It would very greatful to if you can give me a code sample so that i can start with.

Comment: Hmmmm, no, can't do that, sorry. Spend some time googling "How to read a directory in Nodejs" and make an attemps yourself first.

Comment: Can you explain bit, I think i can give you a help

Comment: @Pawansasanka i have updated the question. you can see the example